# Пример приложения со Spring Security

Tags: spring, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно взять пример с применением Spring Security по шагам, а то везде только куски. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security включает в себя сразу много всего. Нельзя расписать всё что есть по шагам в одном туториале.

К тому же, основная [документация по Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html) вполне достаточна по идее. Посмотрите также на [Spring Security Tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html) (в нём и ссылаются на готовое приложение).

Comment: Мне нужен простой пример с работающей авторизацией. Но очень подробный со структурой файлов.

Comment: там уже откомпиленные .class файлы лежат, а мне надо с возможностью поменять логику, т.е. java файлы. Пробовал восствнавливать их декомпилятором, но все равно тогда не меняется логика(

Comment: Так вы что хотите получить? Структуру файлов или всё-таки описание как делать?

Comment: Все таки описание, как на этом примере поменять логику (например, добавить поля).

Comment: не получается изменить java файлы, такое впечатление как он их просто не видит